# How to schedule a job on specific date in rails using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

```rb
notify = @employee_listing.end_publish_date - 3.days
ExpireReminderEmployeeListingWorker.perform_async(notify.to_s, @employee_listing.id)
```

I want to run this worker on this date

```rb
notify = @employee_listing.end_publish_date - 3.days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
perform_at(notify, @employee_listing.id)
```

Comment: What does this do? Why do you recommend using it in this case? Offering an explanation will help future readers better understand not only your thinking, but also the relevant functions.

Comment: `notify` have a date format like this: **Sat, 06 Feb 2021**

Comment: @JeremyCaney This does what was asked. It runs the worker on this date